# vue.js auto reload / refresh data with timer

Tags: javascript, reload, vue.js

(New to Vue.js) I fetch data from a get request to display calendar information. I want this to update every 5 minutes.

Nothing in the docs about auto reload - how would I go about implementing this? Do I use standard javascript within the file or something else?

My complete app.js below:

```
Vue.component('events', {
    template: '#events-template',

    data: function() {
        return {
            list: []
        }
    },

    created: function() {

        this.fetchEventsList();
    },

    methods: {

        fetchEventsList: function() {

            this.$http.get('events', function(events) {

                this.list = events;

            }).bind(this);

        }

    }

});

new Vue({
    el: 'body',


});
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

No need to re-invent the wheel, `window.setInterval()` does the job pretty well

```
Vue.component('events', {
    template: '#events-template',

    data () {
        return {
            list: [],
            timer: ''
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.fetchEventsList();
        this.timer = setInterval(this.fetchEventsList, 300000);
    },
    methods: {
        fetchEventsList () {
            this.$http.get('events', (events) => {
                this.list = events;
            }).bind(this);
        },
        cancelAutoUpdate () {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        }
    },
    beforeUnmount () {
      this.cancelAutoUpdate();
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
});
```

Comment: Suggestion: run `cancelAutoUpdate()` when the component is `destroyed()`